# Browsers does not redirect to app store with app linking on Android

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

We have an app in the store, let's call it com.example.myapplink, though it is something else. In development, app linking is working fine, via Facebook shares by test users, if the app is already installed on the device. If not installed, I'm thinking that the browser is supposed to redirect to the Play Store as shown in Facebook's docs. It does not. I'm using Chrome. Files of interest are below.

HTML being shared on FB:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="myapplink://recipe" />
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example.myapplink" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="My App Link" />
    <meta property="al:web:url" content="http://us.com" />
</head>
 <body>
 <p>Hello World </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

The app's manifest is here. Our version in the store has the same package name but not the newly added intent for app linking. Is this why the browser does not navigate to the store?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplink"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapplink.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.myapplink.LinkActivity"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapplink" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't support app links, so it won't redirect to the play store for you.

Comment: Looking at Facebook's documentation leads me to think it should work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

Comment: That refers to the behavior of the Facebook app on Android, not Chrome or the default browser.

Comment: @Ming Li. Thanks. Do you want to add as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Chrome does not support app links, so it won't automatically redirect to the play store for you.

Comment: Any other browser does?